# get the array value in laravel mail function

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to get the array value in laravel mail function.I have get data value as `$data['users'] =$users;` and passed into mail function as shown below and fetched in view page is also given below.I want to get the request_id with in mail function

```
 $data['users'] =$users; 
 Mail::Send('email.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($data) { 
 $id=$data->request_id  //want to get here
 }

 welcome.blade.php
  @foreach ($users as $user) 
    <td>{{$user->request_id}}</td>
  @endforeach
```

done by

```
$id = $data['users'][0]->req_id;
```

Comment: Does the request_id belong to a user, or is it an unrelated variable?

Comment: I guess he got an array with the user information , passing into a view and want to use the user name in greetings, like Dear UsernameHere,  with Mass maillng function .

Comment: even i was searching for same, but at the end i used foreach loop.